# On Ethereum Goerli, using web3.php, sending a raw Transaction, I get "Transaction Error: invalid sender"

Tags: php, ethereum

yes, I know that Goerli is being deprecated, but it still works on Quicknode. I also know the world is moving to js rpc, but php works too.

This is my transaction data:
transdata:

```
Array(
    [from] => 0x9f49b1261cf9de806908bc1f35b2c0763727acc8
    [to] => 0xB1B019a98E97B28134A268ed9f47620D63225980
    [value] => 0x16345785d8a0000
    [gas] => 0x22
    [gasPrice] => 0x1d
    [nonce] => 0x0
    [chainId] => 2
)
```

To avoid confusion:
1 - The gasPrice is obtained on a call to the node
2 - Nonce is also obtained on a call to the node
3 - The following function is used to determine the gas price limit:

```
function calculateGasPriceLimit($baseGasPrice, $multiplier = 1.2, $minimumLimit = 10){
    // Apply a multiplier to the base gas price
    $gasPriceLimit = bcmul($baseGasPrice, $multiplier);
    
    // Ensure a minimum gas price limit to avoid setting it too low
    $gasPriceLimit = max($gasPriceLimit, $minimumLimit);
    
    return $gasPriceLimit;
}
```

This is the serialized_trans: `0xf865801d2294B1B019a98E97B28134A268ed9f47620D6322598088016345785d8a00008027a01388dc0a117357ae6a9ee73c6304960c73936315d579c3d543ea83db5bd453e5a07e8fd1f6958936f367653a471cd35012c93f34577227d45aded3219cdb59fe9c`

And the result of Ethereum Raw Transaction Decode on https://rawtxdecode.in/

```
  "chainId": "2",
  "type": "LegacyTransaction",
  "valid": true,
  "hash": "0xe1b152179da7be8b043ebeb1d636a392e5dace5983d896db5dc82f3598ca0e2d",
  "nonce": "0",
  "gasPrice": "25",
  "gasLimit": "21000",
  "from": "0x9f49B1261CF9de806908BC1F35b2C0763727ACC8",
  "to": "0xb1b019a98e97b28134a268ed9f47620d63225980",
  "v": "28",
  "r": "6eef88a779d0924d01581f3b3ea270b6de4f3b82ab743b2297e8babee46b8619",
  "s": "182671e8851802daab9b9856c9aae96fe24490384ac751f992c8d1577c813608",
  "value": "100000000000000000"
```

I am extremely frustrated by the lack of documentation and the poor error description on the ethereum network. Please, if someone can spot something wrong with any of this that might be able to help me solve this issue, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I had no faith anyone would actually answer this, so I continued running tests. And finally, Quicknode came through with the final observation that allowed me to get the transaction through to the node.

The chain ID was the problem the whole time. INitially, following the documentation where the chain ID is not included in the transaction data sent, caused the transaction to fail with unknown results. Then using the wrong chain ID continued the saga. The actual chain ID for goerli is 5, not 2. Finally got the transactions to work.